# Why are the pkg-config commands in the makefile not being recognized when I run the script?

Tags: debian, libraries, gnu-make, pkg-config

I am trying to run make for an open-source project on my Debian virtual machine but I do not understand why the commands based on `pkg-config` are not being recognized.

One of the commands is as follows:

```
tempgui-qrps.so: tempgui-qrps.cc refpersys.hh tempgui-qrps.hh tempgui-qrps.moc.hh | $(RPS_CORE_OBJECTS)
    $(RPS_BUILD_CXX) $(RPS_BUILD_COMPILER_FLAGS) \
                         -shared -o $@ -fPIC -Wall -Wextra -O -g \
                  $(shell pkg-config --cflags Qt5Core Qt5Gui Qt5Widgets $(RPS_PKG_NAMES)) \
                  $(shell pkg-config --libs Qt5Core Qt5Gui Qt5Widgets $(RPS_PKG_NAMES)) \
                      -std=gnu++17 \
    $<
```

When I run make on the command line, the output corresponding to the above command looks like this:

```
g++ -std=gnu++17 \                          
    -shared -o tempgui-qrps.so -fPIC -Wall -Wextra -O -g \                
                                  \                
                                   \                      
                                    -std=gnu++17 \ 
tempgui-qrps.cc
```

When I run the make command, I also see these warnings:

```
Package readline was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `readline.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'readline' found
Package zlib was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `zlib.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'zlib' found
```

Are both these problems (absence of packages and the `pkg-config` commands not being processed) related?

Some of the details of `pkg-config` installed on my system are as follows:

```
xxxxx@xxxx:~$ pkg-config --version
0.29

xxxx@xxxx:~$ whereis pkg-config
pkg-config: /usr/bin/pkg-config /usr/lib/pkg-config.multiarch /usr/share/man/man1/pkg-config.1.gz
```

Comment: No *readline.pc*, no *zlib.pc* in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/` : Install `libreadline-dev zlib1g-dev`

Comment: @KnudLarsen Thank you for the response. I believe libreadline-dev is installed on my system. My output for `locate libreadline-dev`: `/usr/share/doc/libreadline-dev`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having `pkg-config` isn’t sufficient: you also need the `.pc` files corresponding to the packages named in each `pkg-config` command.

For `pkg-config --cflags Qt5Core Qt5Gui Qt5Widgets $(RPS_PKG_NAMES)`, you need to install `qtbase5-dev`, and whatever is necessary for the packages in `$(RPS_PKG_NAMES)`. You can install and use `apt-file` to find packages containing specific files.

For `readline` and `zlib`, you need `libreadline-dev` and `zlib1g-dev`. In addition, you’ll need to create `readline.pc` if you’re using Debian 10; place it in `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`, with the following contents:

```
prefix=/usr
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: Readline
Description: Gnu Readline library for command line editing
URL: http://tiswww.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html
Version: 7.0
Requires.private: tinfo
```

(for `amd64`).

You can run the various `pkg-config` commands from the shell to check that they are working, and get information aboit each individual error.

Comment: Thank you for the response. When I run `pkg-config --ldflags Qt5Core` I see the lib files for it. I see similar output when I run `pkg-config --ldflags Qt5Widgets` and `pkg-config --ldflags Qt5Gui`. I have not yet tried running the pkg-config on all of them together as you have suggested.

Comment: You also need to determine the value of `$(RPS_PKG_NAMES)` and check those packages (I suspect that’s where the `readline` and `zlib` errors come from).

Comment: Yes I saw that readline and zlib are both assigned to `$(RPS_PKG_NAMES)`. I also checked they do not have `.pc` files on my system.

Comment: The lack of `readline.pc` is normal, see the details in the answer. If you have the `zlib1g-dev` package installed, you should have `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/zlib.pc` on your system.